# Empty attachement through post WS

Tags: c#, web-services, jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api

I'am trying to send attachement to atlassain Jira, but my files are empty.

```
    string postUrl = url + "/rest/api/2/issue/" + issuekey + "/attachments";


                                        MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();



                                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
                                        HttpContent fileContent1 = new ByteArrayContent(Convert.FromBase64String(docbody));


                                        content.Add(fileContent1, "file", filename);
                                        var response2 = client.PostAsync(postUrl, content).Result;

                                        if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine("OK");
                                        }
```

Comment: Can you try to set headers for file content? For example: `fileContent1.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                        fileContent1.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                        {
                            FileName = "screenshot.png",
                            Name = "foo",
                        };`

Comment: @stuck unfortunately , after adding the code,I Am receiving no attachment